# Principal Components' relation with variables having lower variance

Tags: machine-learning, pca, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

This is a philosophical question about PCA, and not a direct coding question.

I understand that PCA is a dimensionality reduction technique which results in a certain set of PCs, each PC being a linear combination of all the variables in the dataset.

In my use case, I have `n` variables in my dataset, and I'm reducing these `n` variables to `k` PCs, such that, `n > k`. For each of the `k` PCs, I'm extracting the top 2 original variables (with the largest absolute magnitude of loadings) and assuming that those 2 variables (for each PC) contribute the most to that individual PC.

Now, taking each of the top 2 original variables from each PC, I take a `DISTINCT` on the resulting `2k` variables and end up with `m` variables, such that, `n > m`.

For my use case, I would like to figure out what other variables (not contained in `m` variables) are correlated to each of the `m` variables.

For example: Say I have a dataset of users and their ratings on 6 movies `M1,M2,M3,M4,M5 and M6`. The movies `M1` through `M6` will form the 6 original variables (`n=6`) in question. Now say I reduce this to 3 PCs (`k=3`), and after taking `DISTINCT` of the top 2 original variables (`M1` through `M6`) on each PC, say I end up with 2 variables - `M2` and `M4` (`m=2`).

Now I would like to figure out - if a user doesn't like the movie `M2`, what other movies (out of `M1,M3,M5,M6`, the variables not having highest magnitudes for any PC) is the same user less likely to appreciate.

I could just look at the correlation of `M2` with each of `M1,M3,M5 and M6` and the variables with higher correlations would be the answer.

Is there any other statistically sound way to figure this out?

I'm doing this in Python + Pandas + sklearn.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like this can achieve what you're after, but what's the rationale in selecting exactly 2 top variables to represent each PC? It might be the case that the top 100 variables in PC1 individually explain more variance than any of the variables in PC2. Or, it might be the case that none of the variables individually explain variance well at all, and you need some combination of top variables. Highly correlated variables will have similar loadings in PCA space. It sounds like you're trying to find a variance-explaining feature set, and other features highly correlated with them?

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to reinvent Factor Analysis?

Comment: @NuclearWang That's exactly right. I am trying to find a variance-explaining feature set, and other features highly correlated with them. I used choosing top 2 variables as an example. I'm actually picking the variables that fall within 90 percentile of the loadings within each PC. I was wondering if `sklearn` had something out of the box that would be able to achieve this...

Comment: @whuber I have not used Factor Analysis. I will give it a shot.